# How to simply disable a cell that contains text

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have a group of cells that I would like to disable sometimes.

I could go in the menu and uncheck "evaluatable" but the problem is that if there are outpus or texts cells inside of the group, if I uncheck evaluatable and I check it again later, the text and outputs will be evaluated.

Is there a **simple and fast** way to only disable **inputs** of a group of cells ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Options Inspector instead, and search for Evaluatable. Checking and unchecking Evaluatable here does what you want.